# Oracle SQL String to Number conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where the column type is varchar2, and holds data such as '22:00' or "13:30".
I'm trying to compare that number to the current time, and if the current time is before that time, select the data.

Here is my current code:

```
select DISTINCT BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE "Service", BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE "StopNo", 
  STOP_NAME "Near", BBT_STOPS.ROAD_NAME "On", BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME "Duration"

from BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS
inner join BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE
on BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.SERVICE = BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE
inner join BBT_STOPS
on BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE = BBT_STOPS.STOPREF
where  (UPPER(BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE) LIKE UPPER('%'|| :route || '%')) AND 
  (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.TIMEUNTIL, 1, 2)) > (SELECT TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE, 'HH24') "NOW" FROM DUAL));
```

It's the WHERE statement that is having the issues. The error code I get is

```
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
*Action:   Consult your manual.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly call `TO_NUMBER` with a date. You have an implicit `TO_CHAR` happening, and then you're trying to explictly convert that string to a number using a date format model, `HH24`, which is what's giving that error. You don't need the subquery against DUAL either.

Instead of:

```
... > (SELECT TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE, 'HH24') FROM DUAL));
```

you would use:

```
... > TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')));
```

You can also `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE)`. Alternatively you could convert your time string to a date object using today's date and compare more exactly, with something like:

```
... AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || TIMEUNTIL,
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') > SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that condition should be:

```
SUBSTR(BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.TIMEUNTIL, 1, 2) > to_char(sysdate, 'HH24')
```

This part of your filter causes error:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE, 'HH24') "NOW" FROM DUAL
```